# How do you override AddStandardResilenceHandler() for a specific client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

Given the following is set as the default for all clients in the C# project:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(http => {
    // Turn on resilience by default
    http.AddStandardResilienceHandler();

});
```

How does one override the values of that StandardResilienceHandler for a specific Client?

I've tried the following variations:

```
    services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()           
        .AddResilienceHandler("MyClient", (context, next) => {
            context.AddTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        });
```

ignored

```
.AddStandardResilienceHandler(options => {
                options.AttemptTimeout = new HttpTimeoutStrategyOptions {
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                };
                options.TotalRequestTimeout = new HttpTimeoutStrategyOptions {
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
                };
                options.CircuitBreaker.SamplingDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });
```

Also ignored.

I also created a policy like this:

```
var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions

                    .HandleTransientHttpError()
                    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)))
                    .WrapAsync(Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(
                        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                        TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic));
```

and then used this:

```
.AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
```

It still uses the default no matter what.

You'd think this would be easy and documented but I can't find anything in search.

Comment: Adding your GitHub issue here for future readers: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/4814

Comment: Are you sure it is not overridden? I put together a minimal reproducible example based on your question and it seems to me the functionality does work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zsxBIT. Could you please check the example? Did I miss something?

Comment: Well the timeouts definitely don't get overridden after you apply the Standard version and multiple people on the .net team have confirmed it to me.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't do what you want to achieve.

Whenever you call `AddStandardResilienceHandler` or `AddResilienceHandler` it registers a brand new `ResilienceHandler`. That class is currently treated as [internal](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/4759). (So, calling it multiple times will register multiple `ResilienceHandler` instances.)

You might have the temptation to retrieve the `-standard` pipeline itself (*that's the name of the pipeline which is registered by the `AddStandardResilienceHandler` call*) through the `ResiliencePipelineProvider<string>`. The problem with that the retrieved `ResiliencePipeline` it not adjustable directly. It only supports [reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/resilience/http-resilience?tabs=dotnet-cli#dynamic-reload) but that won't help you either...

So all in all, currently this use case is not supported. I would recommend to file an issue on the https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues repository.

Answer (score 0):

For those who haven't found an answer. Call Configure() :

```
.AddStandardResilienceHandler().
Configure(options => ...);
```

Comment: How does configure help? As far as I can tell (and MS confirmed it) it defaults, and it's impossible to override.