Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience: Using AddStandardResilienceHandler options with SlidingWindowRateLimiter
Using Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience is it possible to use precise RateLimiter options, such as SlidingWindowRateLimiter, with the AddStandardResilienceHandler. Alternatively apply the defaults from AddStandardResilienceHandler to a custom AddResilienceHandler definition for everything else other than the RateLimiter part?
Ideally I'd like to use the best practice defaults that are built-in to the resilience library, but override the RateLimiter part for specific API imposed limits.
For example I'd like to combine:
builder.AddStandardResilienceHandler(static options => {
    // Either apply RateLimiter options from below
});

with RateLimiter options such as:
services.AddHttpClient(Constants.StarshipitHttpClient)
    .AddResilienceHandler(Constants.StarshipitHttpClient, static builder =>
    {
        builder.AddRateLimiter(new SlidingWindowRateLimiter(
            new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions
            {
                PermitLimit = 2,
                Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                QueueLimit = int.MaxValue,
            }
        ));

        // Or add other default resiliency options from AddStandardResilienceHandler above  
    });

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Have you checked this SO topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77662135 ?

Thanks Peter, while that SO was useful to read it concerns a slightly different scenario.

I've updated my answer to provide clarity.

Ideally it should be as easy as this:
.AddStandardRResilienceHandler(options => 
{ 
   options.RateLimiter = yourRateLimiterOptions; 
})

But as far as I can see the the reported issue to alter default values is not yet fixed as of writing this answer.

For named HttpClient it works like this
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddHttpClient("test")
    .AddStandardResilienceHandler(options =>
    {
        options.AttemptTimeout.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11);
    });

var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var monitor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<HttpStandardResilienceOptions>>();
var options = monitor.Get("test-standard");
Console.WriteLine(options.AttemptTimeout.Timeout);

using var host = builder.Build();


It registers a named HttpClient with test name
It adds the standard resilience handler to it
It overrides the AttemptTimeout from 10 seconds (the default) to 11
It retrieves an IOptionsMonitor from the DI
It retrieves that HttpStandardResilienceOptions which is named to test-standard

This name is calculated like this $"{httpClientName}-{pipelineIdentifier}"
Where the pipelineIdentifier is standard



The printed output will be 11 seconds, see related dotnet fiddle
The same should work for the RateLimiter property.

Will this method apply all the defaults used by AddStandardResilienceHandler and just override the RateLimiter defaults with my overrides? I was under the impression this wouldn't be the case and I'd need to manually add all the other options to get best practices that AddStandardResilienceHandler provides as default.

@Gavin You can override the options (more or less) independently. If you want to override AttemptTimeout like in the example then the rest of the options remain untouched. I said more or less independently because for example you can't set the AttemptTimeout to 20 seconds because it will throw an OptionsValidationException due to misalignment with Circuit Breaker options.

Thanks Peter, much appreciated. I think you're right and my difficulty is trying to figure out how set the RateLimiterStrategyOptions.RateLimiterto aSlidingWindowRateLimiter`. I'm experimenting now to try to figure it out.

The crux of my problem was that I didn't understand how to override the RateLimiter option for AddStandardResilienceHandler.
After Peter Csala's replies I felt my initial failed attempts were probably user error, so I investigated and experimented more, discovering the need to use AcquireAsync to accomplish the required override:
var rateLimiter = new FixedWindowRateLimiter(
    new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
    {
        PermitLimit = 2,
        Window = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        QueueLimit = int.MaxValue,
    }
);

services.AddHttpClient(name)
    .AddStandardResilienceHandler(options =>
    {
        options.RateLimiter = new HttpRateLimiterStrategyOptions
        {
            Name = $"{name}-{nameof(HttpStandardResilienceOptions.RateLimiter)}",
            RateLimiter = args => rateLimiter.AcquireAsync(cancellationToken: args.Context.CancellationToken)
        };
    });


Yes, that's the way how you should specify a custom rate limiter (as we have documented here).
